# How to modify laravel 5.6 login behaviour? How to add more fields for logging along with email and password?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

Laravel has 2 fields in its auth to help user login i.e **email** and **password**. I have added another field(hidden field)  in the login blade to pass a random number along with a password and email.
In my `eloquentuserprovider.php` i am grabbing `$credentials[‘password’]` and `$credentials[‘email’]` like this but when I write `$credentials[‘hidden’]` I get an error saying `‘undefined index hidden’`.

So my question is how should I add other fields along with email and password to validate the user
I am writing all my validation logic in eloquentuserprovider.php

Comment: are you passing your field like this? `<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="1234">`, also you'll need a same field in User model and database table.

Comment: yes i am passing my field like this. But why would i need a field in user model and table?? I am putting its value from client site and i dont want to put its value in table?

Comment: how are you planning to verify it?

Comment: i will be sending my 'password+random-number' in **password field** and just random-number in my **hidden field** . So my 3 fields at the time of login will be 1)email 2)password 3)hiddenfield. But i am able to grab email and password in eloquentuserprovider.php in validateCredentials function but when it comes to hidden field it says undefined index hidden

Comment: That's because the hidden field is filtered away by the Model's $guarded mass assignment. You may leave `$guarded = []` empty to accept all attributes. But (!) don't forget to delete/unset the hidden field before inserting/updating as the field doesn't exist in the table.